# Auto-start programs maximized in specific workspaces

Tags: workspaces, autostart

How can I auto-start (on login) firefox in the top-left workspace and emacs24 in the top-right workspace, both maximized?

Answer (score 1):

Install `CompizConfig Settings Manager`

In `terminal`:

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manaager`

Start CCSM from the Unity dashboard, and go to the `Window Management` section, choose the `Place Windows` plugin. You'll see this...

[image]

Go to the `Windows with fixed viewport` and add your applications there. You can see in my example I've got 3 applications set to open in various workspaces. Use the `Windows with fixed positions` if you wish to place the app windows in specific locations in their workspace.

Use Ubuntu's own `Startup Applications` app to auto-start your desired apps at login time.